# Ant conditional target not running

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

I have the following ant file:

```
<project name="admin" default="dirCheck" basedir=".">

    <property name="directory" location="node_modules" />

    <target name="run.npm.install" depends="dirCheck" unless="${dirExists}">
        <echo>${directory} does not exist. Running 'npm install'</echo>
        <exec executable="npm">
            <arg value="install" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="run.npm.update" depends="dirCheck" if="${dirExists}">
        <echo>${directory} exists. Running 'npm update'</echo>
        <exec executable="npm">
            <arg value="update" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="node_modules.check">
        <condition property="dirExists">
            <available file="${directory}" type="dir"/>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="dirCheck" depends="node_modules.check">
        <echo>Checking for ${directory}. Exists? ${dirExists}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

For some reason, neither `runNPMInstall` nor `runNPMUpdate` are ever run, regardless of whether the `node_modules` directory exists or not. Anyone have any idea what might be causing this? From all examples online at least one of the dependent tasks should be run.

**EDIT:** Changed:

```
<condition property="dirExists" value="true" else="false">
```

To:

```
<condition property="dirExists">
```

With the same result. Additional information is that I am using Ant `1.8.2`. Thanks for anyone's help!

**EDIT 2:** Updated code to reflect my latest tests. Output from the build for new code above is:

```
Buildfile: /ws_html/app/client/build.xml

node_modules.check:

dirCheck:
     [echo] Checking for /ws_html/app/client/node_modules. Exists? true

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

**Edit 3:** Output when running `ant -debug -f build.xml`:

```
jjung-m2:client-dir jjung$ ant -debug -f build.xml
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 16 2012
Buildfile: /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/build.xml
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Detected OS: Mac OS X
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/build.xml with URI = file:/ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> ClientApp
Adding reference: ClientApp
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> dirCheck
Setting ro project property: ant.file.ClientApp -> /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.ClientApp -> file
Project base dir set to: /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir
 +Target: 
 +Target: run.npm.install
 +Target: run.npm.update
 +Target: node_modules.check
 +Target: dirCheck
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Setting project property: directory -> /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/node_modules
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> dirCheck
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor
Build sequence for target(s) `dirCheck' is [node_modules.check, dirCheck]
Complete build sequence is [node_modules.check, dirCheck, run.npm.update, run.npm.install, ]

node_modules.check:
[available] Found directory: node_modules
Condition true; setting dirExists to true
Setting project property: dirExists -> true

dirCheck:
     [echo] Checking for /ws_html/client-dir/app/client-dir/node_modules. Exists? true

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the build?

Comment: Run your antfile with debuglevel => ant -debug -f build.xml to get more details.

Comment: Updating output to reflect debug level as suggested by Rebse.

Comment: See my edit, from your output it's seen that only dir.check target is run because it's the default target. You need a dependency chain. Even when using Ant 1.8.2 now the old style if/unless="propertyname" will work.

Comment: Exactly, Rebse. That is what I discovered yesterday evening. The problem was that there was no full dependency chain depending on runNPMInstall and runNPMUpdate. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your runNPMInstall target will never run, because the dirExists property will always be set either true or false, because you used [condition task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) with attribute else="false".
When using the old syntax (Ant Version < 1.8.0) , means just the plain propertyname `if="propertyname"` the target is only activated if the property is defined - independent of its actual value. On the contrary `unless="propertyname"` means the target is only activated if the property is not defined, but your property will always be set from condition task => true or false.
Since ant 1.8.0 you may use the new syntax `if="${propertyname}` means the target is only activated if the property holds true | yes | on, respectively `unless="${propertyname}"` means the target will only be activated if the property hold false | no | off, [see ant manual if / unless](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless)
When using if / unless with ${propertyname} it should work as expected with Ant >= 1.8.0
Alternatively use the condition task without the else attribute to make it work with the old syntax :

```
The value to set the property to if the condition evaluates to false. By default the property will remain unset.
```

Also `value="true"` is not needed, as :

```
The value to set the property to. Defaults to "true".
```

So that should be sufficient to make it work 'old style' :

```
<condition property="dirExists">
 <available file="${directory}" type="dir"/>
</condition>
```

**-- EDIT after comment --**
When starting your ant file it will run the default target dir.check and nothing else happens. Use :
`<project name="admin" default="main" basedir=".">`
and create a new target :
`<target name="main" depends="dir.check,runNPMInstall,runNPMUpdate"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually discovered that could have been the case. However, if I do as you suggest runNPMInstall and runNPMUpdate still do not ever run! I'm trying everything I can think of and scouring the web, but no matter what I do the only way that runNPMUpdate and runNPMInstall are ever run is if I make them the default target. I've update the question to account for your response.Thanks.

Comment: OK, when running Ant 1.7 the new syntax is no option but it should run with your changes in edit !? Use debuglevel to see what's going on

Comment: Your EDIT after comment is the correct solution. Really appreciate it!